# Как правильно заходить в контейнер docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

не могу понять как правильно заходить и выходить из контейнера docker

```
lemp_mariadb   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      3306/tcp                                   
lemp_nginx     /init                         Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp 
lemp_php       /init                         Up      9000/tcp
```

Вывожу список id

docker-compose ps -q

```
4ff63ed255932e5a7409bdff253c4974c31f1a0d816821316788c00cf0050726
8528527773d4ca6078de49c998d7b4067e0b67e715663570a310cae70d125679
bb4d896c13be0c6c59ec8ec9a85a3269e048b0e28f97c10ae670ab948d542062
```

docker exec -it 4ff63ed255932e5a7409bdff253c4974c31f1a0d816821316788c00cf0050726 /bin/bash

захожу в первый образ, все гуд
В последующие образы выдает ошибку

***rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\"/bin/bash\\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory\"\n"***

Плюс ко всему, есть какой то короткий способ заходить в контейнер ?
И как вывести id контэйнера в ps, но только с именем контэйнера

Comment: Покажите dockerfile контейнера. Похоже у вас там нет bash.

Comment: Разобрался, sh просто

Comment: оформите ответ и примите его. Это поможет другим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оказалось, что не все образы имеют bash, поэтому вместо команды

```
docker exec -it 4ff63ed255932e5a7409bdff253c4974c31f1a0d816821316788c00cf0050726 /bin/bash
```

надо ввести

```
docker exec -it 4ff63ed255932e5a7409bdff253c4974c31f1a0d816821316788c00cf0050726 sh
```

Плюс ко всему id(4ff63ed255932e5a7409bdff253c4974c31f1a0d816821316788c00cf0050726) можно заменить на имя контейнера

В моем случае это выглядит так

```
docker exec -i-t lemp_nginx sh
```

Comment: не забудьте принять ваш ответ как правильный